# recursion method in binary search tree-java

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

I am trying to write a boolean recursive method that inserts values into a binary search tree. It returns true if the value is not already there and inserts it and returns false if there already is that same value there and the list does not get changed. I think this works for the most part, but it fails to return false repetitively when multiple values are already there. For example, if the tree already contains 3 9 6 7 and I try to insert 3, it returns false as it is the first time. But then when I try to insert 9 6 or 7, it always returns true, which it should not as those values are already there.

```
public boolean insert(int value) {
    Node travel;
    travel=insert(value,root);
    if (travel==null)
        return false;
    root=travel;
    return true;
}

private Node insert(int value, Node travel) {
    if (travel==null) {
        travel=new Node(value);
        return travel;  
    }
    if (value>travel.data) {
        travel.right=(insert(value,travel.right));
        return travel;
    }
    if(value<travel.data) {
        travel.left=(insert(value,travel.left));
        return travel;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: The code itself looks fine Lori. It is possible that your tree has orphaned nodes after the first insert, causing future inserts to return true.

Comment: @algorithmic the code is wrong. Assume the tree contains 3 6 9 7 with root 3. When you try to insert a 6 the second if case is matched. The recursive call of insert will set the right descendant of 3 to some value. But returned will be the node with value 3.

Comment: @User - on the first call to insert(value,travel), the second case is matched. in that case insert(value, travel.right) is called and now null is returned. that is what travel.right will be set to when coming out of the recursion. and return travel will return null. So it does work ok, in the the first insert case. However the insert code is not actually shown. so, it is unclear what changed with the second insert case - that is when insert(9) is called.

Comment: @algorithmic travel cant be null. If it was null the first case would match what do you mean that the insert code is not shown?!  Its a recursive call so everything is shown.

Comment: @user - the actual insertion into the tree is not shown. if this is the only code and the tree is preconstructed, the code has no issues. what do you mean travel cant be null? if the value is neither greater nor smaller, then the last return is reached "return null".

Comment: @algorithmic if value<travel.data, insert will be called with travel.right, regardless of whether or not travel.right is null. Presumably OP is using null to represent non-existent nodes

Comment: @raptortech97 - that is a possibility I had not considered. True, in that case it would hit the if (travel==null) case, create a new Node and return that, essentially resulting in a "true" being returned for an insert of a value that already exists.

Answer (score 1):

Change it like this:

```
private Node insert(int value, Node current) {
    if(current.data == value){
        return current;
    }else if(current.left != null && current.left.data > value){
        return insert(value,current.left);
    }else if(current.right != null && current.right.data < value){
        return insert(value,current.right);
    }else{
        if(current.data > value){
            current.left = new Node(value);
        }else{
            current.right = new Node(value);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

This will insert the a Node with the given value if its not already present and return null. Otherwise a Node will be returned which indicates that the Node was already present.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be something like

Initially call with `insert(value, root, null)`

```
public boolean insert(int value, Node currentNode, Node parentNode) {
    if(currentNode == null) { //Node not present, hence insert
         Node valueNode = new Node(value);
         if(parentNode != null && parentNode.value > value) { //link to the parent node
             parentNode.left = valueNode;
         } else if(parentNode != null && parentNode.value < value){
             parentNode.right = valueNode;
         }
         return true; 
    } else if(currentNode.value = value) { //Node present 
         return false;
    } else if(value > currentNode.value) { //Now check the same in right side of the tree
         return insert(value, currentNode.right, currentNode);
    } else if(value < currentNode.value) { //Now check the left side of the tree
         return insert(value, currentNode.left, currentNode);
    }
}
```